# Generating constant RSA keys (Java)

Tags: java, rsa

I would want the generating of the RSA to be constant with the same public key and private key, no matter how many time I generates.

I have a java source code which the keys(public key and private key) will change every time I generate it.

How can I modify the codes so that it will be constant every time I generate it?

```
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 *  This class encrypts and decrypts a file using CipherStreams
 *  and a 256-bit Rijndael key. The key is then encrypted using
 *  a 1024-bit RSA key, which is password-encrypted.
 */
public class FileEncryptorRSA {
/**
*   When files are encrypted, this will be appended to the end
*   of the filename.
*/
private static final String ENCRYPTED_FILENAME_SUFFIX=".encrypted";

  /**
 *  When files are decrypted, this will be appended to the end
 *  of the filename.
 */
private static final String DECRYPTED_FILENAME_SUFFIX=".decrypted";

/**
 *  Number of times the password will be hashed with MD5
 *  when transforming it into a TripleDES key.
 */
private static final int ITERATIONS = 1000;

/**
 *  FileEncryptor is started with one of three options:
 *
 *  -c: create key pair and write it to 2 files
 *  -e: encrypt a file, given as an argument
 *  -d: decrypt a file, given as an argument
 */
public static void main (String[] args)
throws Exception {
if ((args.length < 1) || (args.length > 2)) {
  usage();
} else if ("-c".equals(args[0])) {
  createKey();
} else if ("-e".equals(args[0])) {
  encrypt(args[1]);
} else if ("-d".equals(args[0])) {
  decrypt(args[1]);
} else {
  usage();
}
}

private static void usage() {
System.err.println("Usage: java FileEncryptor -c|-e|-d [filename]");
System.exit(1);
}

/**
 *  Creates a 1024 bit RSA key and stores it to
 *  the filesystem as two files.
 */
private static void createKey()
throws Exception {
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.print("Password to encrypt the private key: ");
String password = in.readLine();
System.out.println("Generating an RSA keypair...");

// Create an RSA key
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyPairGenerator.initialize(1024);
KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair();

System.out.println("Done generating the keypair.\n");

// Now we need to write the public key out to a file
System.out.print("Public key filename: ");
String publicKeyFilename = in.readLine();

// Get the encoded form of the public key so we can
// use it again in the future. This is X.509 by default.
byte[] publicKeyBytes = keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded();

// Write the encoded public key out to the filesystem
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(publicKeyFilename);
fos.write(publicKeyBytes);
fos.close();

// Now we need to do the same thing with the private key,
// but we need to password encrypt it as well.
System.out.print("Private key filename: ");
String privateKeyFilename = in.readLine();

// Get the encoded form. This is PKCS#8 by default.
byte[] privateKeyBytes = keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded();

// Here we actually encrypt the private key
byte[] encryptedPrivateKeyBytes =
passwordEncrypt(password.toCharArray(),privateKeyBytes);

fos = new FileOutputStream(privateKeyFilename);
fos.write(encryptedPrivateKeyBytes);
fos.close();
}

/**
 *  Encrypt the given file with a session key encrypted with an
 *  RSA public key which will be read in from the filesystem.
 */
private static void encrypt(String fileInput)
throws Exception {

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.print("Public Key to encrypt with: ");
String publicKeyFilename = in.readLine();

// Load the public key bytes
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(publicKeyFilename);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int theByte = 0;
while ((theByte = fis.read()) != -1)
{
  baos.write(theByte);
}
fis.close();

byte[] keyBytes = baos.toByteArray();
baos.close();

// Turn the encoded key into a real RSA public key.
// Public keys are encoded in X.509.
X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);

// Open up an output file for the output of the encryption
String fileOutput = fileInput + ENCRYPTED_FILENAME_SUFFIX;
DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream
(new FileOutputStream(fileOutput));

// Create a cipher using that key to initialize it
Cipher rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
rsaCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

// Now create a new 256 bit Rijndael key to encrypt the file itself.
// This will be the session key.
KeyGenerator rijndaelKeyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("Rijndael");
rijndaelKeyGenerator.init(256);
System.out.println("Generating session key...");
Key rijndaelKey = rijndaelKeyGenerator.generateKey();
System.out.println("Done generating key.");

// Encrypt the Rijndael key with the RSA cipher
// and write it to the beginning of the file.
byte[] encodedKeyBytes= rsaCipher.doFinal(rijndaelKey.getEncoded());
output.writeInt(encodedKeyBytes.length);
output.write(encodedKeyBytes);

// Now we need an Initialization Vector for the symmetric cipher in CBC mode
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
byte[] iv = new byte[16];
random.nextBytes(iv);

// Write the IV out to the file.
output.write(iv);
IvParameterSpec spec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

// Create the cipher for encrypting the file itself.
Cipher symmetricCipher = Cipher.getInstance("Rijndael/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
symmetricCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, rijndaelKey, spec);

CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(output, symmetricCipher);

System.out.println("Encrypting the file...");

FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileInput);

theByte = 0;
while ((theByte = input.read()) != -1)
{
  cos.write(theByte);
}
input.close();
cos.close();
System.out.println("File encrypted.");
return;
}

/**
 *  Decrypt the given file.
 *  Start by getting the RSA private key
 *  and decrypting the session key embedded
 *  in the file. Then decrypt the file with
 *  that session key.
 */
private static void decrypt(String fileInput)
throws Exception {

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.print("Private Key to decrypt with: ");
String privateKeyFilename = in.readLine();

System.out.print("Password for the private key: ");
String password = in.readLine();

// Load the private key bytes
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(privateKeyFilename);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int theByte = 0;
while ((theByte = fis.read()) != -1)
{
  baos.write(theByte);
}
fis.close();

byte[] keyBytes = baos.toByteArray();
baos.close();

keyBytes = passwordDecrypt(password.toCharArray(), keyBytes);

// Turn the encoded key into a real RSA private key.
// Private keys are encoded in PKCS#8.
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);

// Create a cipher using that key to initialize it
Cipher rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");

// Read in the encrypted bytes of the session key
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileInput));
byte[] encryptedKeyBytes = new byte[dis.readInt()];
dis.readFully(encryptedKeyBytes);

// Decrypt the session key bytes.
rsaCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
byte[] rijndaelKeyBytes = rsaCipher.doFinal(encryptedKeyBytes);

// Transform the key bytes into an actual key.
SecretKey rijndaelKey = new SecretKeySpec(rijndaelKeyBytes, "Rijndael");

// Read in the Initialization Vector from the file.
byte[] iv = new byte[16];
dis.read(iv);
IvParameterSpec spec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Rijndael/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, rijndaelKey, spec);
CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(dis, cipher);

System.out.println("Decrypting the file...");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileInput + DECRYPTED_FILENAME_SUFFIX);

// Read through the file, decrypting each byte.
theByte = 0;
while ((theByte = cis.read()) != -1)
{
  fos.write(theByte);
}
cis.close();
fos.close();
System.out.println("Done.");
return;
}

   /**
   *    Utility method to encrypt a byte array with a given password.
   *    Salt will be the first 8 bytes of the byte array returned.
   */
private static byte[] passwordEncrypt(char[] password, byte[] plaintext) throw Exception        {

// Create the salt.
byte[] salt = new byte[8];
Random random = new Random();
random.nextBytes(salt);

// Create a PBE key and cipher.
PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password);
SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithSHAAndTwofish-CBC");
SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
PBEParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, ITERATIONS);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithSHAAndTwofish-CBC");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);

// Encrypt the array
byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(plaintext);

// Write out the salt, then the ciphertext and return it.
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
baos.write(salt);
baos.write(ciphertext);
return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

/**
   *    Utility method to decrypt a byte array with a given password.
   *    Salt will be the first 8 bytes in the array passed in.
   */
  private static byte[] passwordDecrypt(char[] password, byte[] ciphertext) throws   Exception{

```
// Read in the salt.
byte[] salt = new byte[8];
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(ciphertext);
bais.read(salt,0,8);

// The remaining bytes are the actual ciphertext.
byte[] remainingCiphertext = new byte[ciphertext.length-8];
bais.read(remainingCiphertext,0,ciphertext.length-8);

// Create a PBE cipher to decrypt the byte array.
PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password);
SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithSHAAndTwofish-CBC");
SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
PBEParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, ITERATIONS);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithSHAAndTwofish-CBC");

// Perform the actual decryption.
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
return cipher.doFinal(remainingCiphertext);
  }
}
```

The file can be review @ http://sce.uhcl.edu/yang/teaching/proJavaSecurityCode/Chapter5/FileEncryptorRSA.java

I would appreciate for the full guide solution. Much Thanks!

EDITED:
Can any kind soul provide me with the code to download??
The generator must generate the same keys every time with a session key input

Comment: I understand it is an unreasonably demand but I am completing with time. I hope some kind soul can help!

Comment: How about generating them once, making a copy and shipping the copy in your code? On request just dump the constant.

Comment: That doesnt allow my code to works :-( sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your posted code only generates a new keypair when it is called with a -c commandline argument.  Otherwise it uses the generated public / private keypair stored via -c to encrypt and decrypt.  If you use only -e and -d you will not need to regenerate your keypair.

generation of a keypair is non-trivial.  The whole point behind it is that the private key is supposed to be secret.  If you alter the code to always generate the same key, that breaks any security offered by the encryption scheme.

Perhaps if you explained why you need it to behave in this manner we'd be able to provide more help.

Comment: I know it is a security flaw but I need the code it works that way. Thanks with Cheer!

Answer (score 1):

A chance answer but looking through everything my plan would be to fub the randomness of it.

The randomness is generated by:

```
// Create an RSA key
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyPairGenerator.initialize(1024);
KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair();
```

If you look at javadoc: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/KeyPairGenerator.html

I think you want to change fub the randomness by altering the SecureRandom.
    initialize(AlgorithmParameterSpec params, SecureRandom random) - 
    Initializes the key pair generator with the given parameter set and source of randomness.

Maybe implementing your own which is not random? But I agree with the post by mcfinnigan wondering why you would do it...

Comment: As I need to integrate into my program which need to run without salt at start

Comment: Your last sentence is the only way it would work if you want to use the JCE `KeyPairGenerator` class.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, why do you want to do this? When you generate a key-pair, you usually want to use a [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) in addition to the passphrase, and the salt should be unpredictable so that it provides an extra level of protection against brute-force attacks.

I think Ragshi is right that you need to supply a `SecureRandom` implementation to `keyPairGenerator.initialize()`, but you should probably set the seed of an instance from `SecureRandom.getInstance()` rather than implementing your own non-random algorithm.

Sorry, I misread the code at first and thought the relevant part was the method `passwordEncrypt` where salt is generated using the `Random` class. I can't delete my post so I've tried to correct it instead.

Comment: It aright. Anyone solution for the code to run without salting?

Comment: Your solution will not work. You need to implement your own instance of SecureRandom.

Comment: Can you say why it won't work? I'm sure you are right but I would like to understand better.